# Moving an object on the edge of a circle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, geometry

I am working on combat mechanics in a Top Down 2D game. I want to create a circle around a player and move the object on the edge of that circle. No matter where your mouse is, the object always stays on the edge. How would I do that? I know this is related to math but I am yet inexperienced to implement it on the right way. Here is a picture of the idea and the question itself. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXQTL.png).

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to know how does the user controls the player.

Anyway, here's some piece of code that i used on a 2D project of mine. Not sure if it works on 3D, but even if it doesn't, the logic is the same

```
float radius = 400; //radius of circle
Vector3 playerPosition = player.transform.position; //Player's position 
Vector3 centerPosition = transform.localPosition; //center of the circle
float distance = Vector3.Distance(playerPosition, centerPosition); //distance from player to the center of the circle

if (distance > radius) //If the distance is greater than the radius, it is already within the circle
{
   Vector3 fromOriginToObject = playerPosition - centerPosition;
   fromOriginToObject *= radius / distance; //Multiply by radius //Divide by Distance
   Vector3 newPlayerPosition = centerPosition + fromOriginToObject; //all that Math
}

player.transform.localPosition = newPlayerPosition ;
```

I really encourage you to check the font as it have some visual explanation: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1309521/how-to-keep-an-object-within-a-circlesphere-radius.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll definetely look into it. About the game, I've already specified that the game is in 2D + I've said it's topdown if you've read the question. The player is controlled using the keyboard, reading the input from "Input.GetAxis".

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You will need the radius and center of the circle. Then probably some vector that defines the direction.

Comment: The center of the circle in this case is the Player. And the direction is defined by the mouse position. `mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); // Gets the position of the mouse'. I've already done that. But I am struggling on how to keep the object moving around the elipse of the circle